# Its all about functions

Tags: functions

Let $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$ and for all $t \ge 0$,
$$f(x) = f(xe^t).$$

Show that $f$ is a constant function.

I tried finding out its derivative but it didn't lead me anywhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: to those who downvoted it may i know whats the problem?

Comment: Well, you'd have to prove the function was differentiable first.  Hint:  take first  prove that $f(x)=f(1)$ for all $x>0$  (Note:  I did not downvote the question but I assume that those who did were objecting to the lack of shown effort).

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  Please type out your calculations for what you've tried (i.e. $f'$).

Comment: @AvnishSingh It is not neccesary, but editing your question title may makes the question clearer.

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb R$. Let $s >0$ and let $y = xe^{-s}$. We have $f(y) = f(ye^{r})$ for every $r > 0$. So, $f(xe^{-s}) = f(xe^{r-s})$ for every $r > 0$. In particular, $f(x) = f(xe^{-s})$. This is true for every $s>0$. Hence,

$$f(x) = \lim_{s \to \infty} f(xe^{-s}) = f(x\times 0) = f(0)$$

where in the second equality we used the continuity of $f$.

This shows that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall x \in (\mathbb R^+\cup\mathbb R^-), \forall u\gt1, f(xu)=f(x)$$
$\implies \forall x,y\in\mathbb R^+, f(x)=f(y)$ and $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R^-, f(x)=f(y)$

By continuity, $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R, f(x)=f(y)$